# How can I load a bunch of array elements from a text file?

Tags: c++

How could I load array from a text file in C++.

I can't get all array elements from the file.

and here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{

    ifstream file("file.txt");
    if(file.is_open())
        string myArray[5];

}
```

Comment: Why do you believe that declaring an array in your code magically puts the contents into a text file?

Comment: What is the format of your text file? How are the array elements delimited?

Comment: Are you trying to read values from a file into an array, or write the contents of the array into a file.  "How could I load array into a text file" and "can't get all the array elements into the file" sound like output operations.  Maybe you mean "How could I load an array from a text file" and "I can't get all the array elements from the file".

Comment: @JonathonLeffler exactly i can't get all the array elements from the file.

Comment: A sample of the input file is necessary to provide you with a usable answer.

Comment: Please search the internet for "c++ read file array".  There are already many similar posts on StackOverflow.

Comment: From "the file" does not explain what do you need to do with the file content. Is it JSON XML or what is needed to be parsed as array?

Answer (score 0):

When reading from a file, the advice is to use a dynamic container, such as `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<int> database;
int number;
ifstream data_file("file.txt");
while (data_file >> number)
{
  database.push_back(number);
}
```

The above fragment will read integers from the file, regardless of the quantity.

### Arrays

The issue with arrays is that you need to know the quantity before you declare the array.

```
const size_t capacity = 16;
int array[capacity];
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < capacity; ++i)
{
  data_file >> array[i];
};
```

The above fragment assumes that there is at least 16 numbers in the file.

Answer (score 0):

you will make counter to continute counting the data until you stop reading from the file then open an array it's size = this counter , then open new counter say to put the fisrt number in the first index in the array and here is the code

```
        int i=0 , j=0 ;
    ifstream file("statfile.txt") ;

    while(file >> data) {i++ ;}
    double arr[i];
    file.close();

    ifstream newfile("statfile.txt");
    while(newfile >> arr[j]) {j++ ;}
    for(j=0 ; j<i ; j++) {cout << arr[j] << " " ;}
```